# How exactly does MongoDB chunk migration work?

Tags: mongodb

After reading about [chunk-migration-procedure](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/#chunk-migration-procedure), I still have a few questions.

1. Does the destination shard finish transferring the chunk before start to synchronizing the update to the chunk that comes during the transfer?
2. How does the destination shard determine that it is fully synchronized? What if some updates on the chunk come while it is updating the metadata on the config server?

Answer (score 4):

The following info should be generally correct as at MongoDB 3.2, but there may be some implementation differences for older (or newer) releases.

> 1. Does the destination shard finish transferring the chunk before start to synchronizing the update to the chunk that comes during the transfer?

Yes, that is steps 4 & 5 in the [chunk migration procedure](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/sharding-balancer-administration/#chunk-migration-procedure):

4. The destination shard begins requesting documents in the chunk and starts receiving copies of the data.
5. After receiving the final document in the chunk, the destination shard starts a synchronization process to ensure that it has the changes to the migrated documents that occurred during the migration.

A [chunk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-chunk) represents a continuous range of shard key values within a particular shard and (as at MongoDB 3.2) does not confer any on-disk locality for the documents in that range. The migration process starts tracking all updates to documents in the chunk being migrated from the source shard, builds required indexes on the destination shard, copies over the initial documents in the chunk range, and then goes into a cycle of applying any updates that have yet to be propagated to the destination shard.

> 2. How does the destination shard determine that it is fully synchronized?

During the cycle of applying updates, the migration process waits for pending updates to reach a state where the source and destination shard are close to (or perhaps even fully) synchronized. At this point migration enters a *critical section* where updates and reads to the chunk's collection on the source shard are blocked, any final data changes are transferred, and the sharded cluster metadata stored on the config servers is updated with the new chunk ownership information.

> What if some updates on the chunk come while it is updating the metadata on the config server?

Updates will be blocked while the migration process is in the *critical section*. When migration successfully exits the critical section, the shard version will be incremented and a `StaleConfigException` will be returned for any blocked requests. The stale config exception is the cue for `mongos` to reload the current version of the sharded cluster metadata and re-send requests to the correct shard(s).

If you're curious to find out more (and amenable to reading C++), the relevant source path in MongoDB 3.2 is [`src/mongodb/s/`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/v3.2/src/mongo/db/s).

Comment: Nice explanations. You mean a `StaleConfigException` is sent to mongos ? And clients are unware of this and will not timeout ? Or clients should retry the blocked-and-failed requests ?

Comment: @LewisChan My description is what happens from the `mongos` point of view. Clients are not aware of chunk migrations and do not need any special logic to handle reads or writes while data is being actively migrated. During the brief _critical section_ where a migration completes and the cluster metadata is updated, pending requests for that collection are queued at the `mongos` until the critical section completes. This is [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)) in the computing context of waiting on an event, not a failed request.